# Removing an Accessory View from a UITableViewCell When The Cell is Not Selected and maintaining between reloading views

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, accessoryview

I have what I believe to be a simple problem, but I can't find a solution to it.

I have a static `UITableView` with two static `cells` (Light and Dark).

When the user selects one of the cells, I'm displaying an accessoryView with a custom image. When the user selects the other cell, I want the first cell to deselect and to remove the custom accessoryView and for that to be provided to the secondCell. I want this to continuously do this depending on which cell the user selects.

Of equal importance, I need to make sure the "selected" cell maintains the accessoryView throughout the reloading of this view controller (with the use of `NSUserDefaults`).

How would I go about doing this? I'm fairly new to iOS development.

Here's some code in my didSelectRow:

```
 BOOL isSelected;

if (cell.isSelected) {
    UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 10, 14, 15)];
    dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-white-hi.png"];
    [cell addSubview:dot];
    cell.accessoryView = dot;
    isSelected = YES;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    isSelected = NO;
}
```

Any assistance would really be appreciated with removing the accessory view from one of the cells and to the other, and also how to maintain this throughout the lifecycle of the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a property in your .h file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSIndexPath * checkedIndexPath ;
```

synthesize in your .m file

```
@synthesize checkedIndexPath;
```

write this code in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
   UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
    uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}
else
{
   UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: That works like absolutely brilliantly. Many thanks for that. How would I maintain this UITbleViewCellAccessoryCheckmark for the selected cell when the view is reloaded? If I select this cell, go to another view and come back, the "selected" cell does not maintain there?

Comment: I've asked another question regarding the NSUserDefaults and maintaining the selected state: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764081/maintaining-a-selected-uitableviewcells-accessory-type-throughout-app-lifecycle - Thanks for your help on this