# How to remove check marks from selected table view cell's, when editing mode is enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uikit

I don't want to show check marks when user select multiple rows in table view. I also want bit smaller selection indicator view with different color.
I am enabling this selection style by setting editing mode

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

Is there any way to set custom view/style for this type of selection?

[image]

Comment: hope this will work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762560/removing-an-accessory-view-from-a-uitableviewcell-when-the-cell-is-not-selected/22762717#22762717

Comment: @MayankJain I don't want accessory view, I want to show selection in left side of cell and selection should be of blue color circle but without check mark. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to create your custom one... IOS default does not support it.

Comment: Not possible. You have to create your own

Answer (score 0):

I am very sure that there is no api allowing you to specify a custom view for any of the editing controls that appear on the left (the delete control, insertion control, or either version of the selection control).

But you can achieve this another way. At a high level it would be like this:

- Don't set `editing` on the table view.
- Do set `allowsMultipleSelection` instead of `allowsMultipleSelectionWhenEditing`.
- If you are using the built-in `Edit` button change it to your own Edit button with an action that sets a flag like `isInCustomEditMode`. The action will also need to toggle between the `Edit` and `Cancel` button.
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check that flag. If set then display the cell with your own view control.
- In the `didSelect...` and `didDeselect...` methods set your custom view to match the state of the cell.

If your designer allows it you could also consider not displaying the selection control at all. I would argue that the highlighting in the cell when it is selected is indication enough to the user that the cell is indeed selected.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have below two lines in your code,Remove these below two lines

table.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

[table setEditing:YES animated:NO];

Instead,You want Multiple selection
 **table.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;**

Its not displaying the selection control.